# Locus in the case of an ellipse.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, locus, geometric-transformation

Given that $ S $ is the focus on the positive x-axis of the equation$ \frac{x^{2}}{25} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} =1$.
Let $P=(5 \cos{t}, 3 \sin {t})$ on the ellipse,
$SP$ is produced to $Q$ so that $PQ = 2PS$.
Find the locus of $ Q $ if $P$ moves on the ellipse.
I found that $S=(4,0)$ and try to use the line segment formula but cannot get the answer as stated below.
The answer back is $\frac{(x+8)^{2}}{15} +\frac {y^{2}}{9}=1$
Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homothety is a key word. You get a point $Q$ if you act on $P$ with a homothety with center at $S$ and factor $k=3$. So since homothety preserves shape, the result is again ellipse with a center at $(-8,0)$ and $a'=3a = 15$ and $b'=3b =9$. So we get $$  \frac{(x+8)^{2}}{15^2} +\frac {y^{2}}{9^2}=1$$

Comment: Can you do it in an more elementary way other than using the concept of homothety?

Comment: You don't know what is homothety?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not in my school syllabus.And also after finding the internet it seems like enlargement, am I right?

Comment: You just resize whole picture from the $S$ with factor 3. Is that more elementary?

Comment: Try to draw it say in geogebra.

Comment: And also do you meant S is extended to P and extended more to Q in the same direction?

Comment: No, $S$ is fixed, you have to extend $P$ to $Q$.

Comment: And also why the centre is shifted to (-8,0)?

Comment: How far is center of given ellipse to $S$?

Comment: And also the denominator of the answer is 15 and 9 not 15^2 and 9^2 ,but I can't sure whether there is a typo or not.

Comment: Actually using the line segment formula I manage to get denominator as 15^2 and 9^2 but the denominator of the answer is 15 and 9 so I think I am wrong.But if you also get the same answer then I will reconsider it.

Comment: That's clearly a misprint in the book.

Answer (score 1):

As $Q=P+2(P-S)$, the coordinates of $Q$ can be readily found to be:
$$
x_Q=3x_P-8=15\cos t-8,\quad
y_Q=3y_P=9\sin t.
$$
It follows that $(x_Q+8)^2/15^2+y_Q^2/9^2=1$.

Comment: Another answer convincing me that the answer of my book has a typo.